# How to reference static classes in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I apologize in advance for the newbiness of this question; I think I'm not grasping the basics of Actionscript but haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere.

What I want is some global constants like one would have in C++. In C++, I would simply have a file where I would #define MAP_HEIGHT 20, or something like that, and they would be globally accessible when I included the file at the top. In Actionscript, I've tried making a static class instead, like so:

```
package  
{
public class Settings {

    public const mapx:int = 20;

    public function Settings() {}

}
}
```

But when I try to reference it in my code with colon syntax

```
var a:int = Settings::mapx;
```

I get the error "[Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Settings$ to Namespace."

I tried dot syntax:

```
var a:int = Settings.mapx;
```

and got a different error, "Access of possibly undefined property mapx through a reference with static type Class."

But what I really want is a file of global static variables, like in C++, and can't find a way to do it in Actionscript.

Comment: where do you define the `a` var? Basically the dot syntax is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark variables, constants, and functions with the [`static`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#static) keyword, as in:

```
package
{
    public class MathUtil
    {

        public static const PI:Number = 3.141592653589;

        public static function deg2rad(angle:Number):Number
        {
            angle = !isNaN(angle) ? (angle) : (0);

            return angle * PI / 180;
        }

    }
}
```

Then you may use dot notation.

```
var pi:Number = MathUtil.PI;
var angle:Number = MathUtil.deg2rad(45);
```

From ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform: [Statements, Keywords & Directives](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#static)

> #### *Usage*
>
> ```
> class someClassName { 
>   static var varName; 
>   static const kName;
>   static function methodName() { }
> }
> ```
>
> You can use static in class definitions only, not in interface
>   definitions.
>
> Static class members are not inherited. You cannot refer to a static
>   class member using the name of a subclass, as you can in Java or C++.
>   You can, however, refer to a static variable or method within a class
>   or subclass, without using any qualifier. See the example below.
>
> You cannot use the super statement or the `this` keyword inside a static
>   method.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong, I tried it 15 ways, but when I deleted everything and did just as you said, it worked. Thanks, and thanks for taking the time for such a basic question.